# TACACS authentication: is it possible to get the user groups or other attributes?

Tags: authentication, tacacs

TACACS is a networking protocol that provides centralized Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting (AAA) management https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACACS

The question if is it possible to get the user groups or other attributes.
According my understanding the answer is not but I will happy to clarify if I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

nothing in the RFC about user Groups https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1492

P.S: You should upgrade to RADIUS or DIAMETER. TACACS is just so old.